# preg_replace IF tag statement

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I use this code

```
$text = '
[IF=is_login]
    [IF=is_subscriber]subscriber[/IF]
    [IF=is_partner]partner[/IF]
[/IF]';
$count = 0; 
do 
{ 
    $content = preg_replace ("#\\[IF=(.+?)\\](.*?)\\[/IF\\]#ies", "the_if('\\1', '\\2', FALSE)", $text, -1, $count); 
} 
while ($count > 0);
```

Ie to be a hierarchy, but it turns out that the function returns all that goes to the first [/IF]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There were extra escape slashes, and you need to set `$text`, not `$content`, so that it gets replaced during the loop

```
$text = preg_replace ("#\[IF=(.+?)\](.*?)\[/IF\]#ies", "the_if('$1', '$2', FALSE)", $text, -1, $count);
```

Comment: first output = [IF=is_subscriber]subscriber, but need   [IF=is_subscriber]subscriber[/IF]
[IF=is_partner]partner[/IF]

Comment: This is what I get when I take out the `e` execute flag: `the_if('is_login', '
    the_if('is_subscriber', 'subscriber', FALSE)
    the_if('is_partner', 'partner', FALSE)
', FALSE)`, which seems correct. Might help to see or know what `the_if()` is supposed to do